# Calculate the inscribed circle between 2 lines and a circle

Tags: geometry

**Update**: [Here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/HubertApollonius2Lines.shtml#solution) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_cases_of_Apollonius%27_problem#Type_8:_One_circle.2C_two_lines) I've found an explanation of the problem

As far as my understanding goes, by finding the intersection of two lines and calculating the angle, then dividing it by two, a line can be obtained which passes through the center of the circle.

[image: Image of the situation]

As an example I have 2 lines, and a circle:

```
Line 1
x1 = 7
y1 = 10
x2 = 11
y2 = 6

Line 2
x3 = 12
y3 = 3
x4 = 5
y4 = 0

Circle
rad = 2
xc  = 2
yc  = 8
```

And I want to calculate the centerpoint and radius of the circle touching those (tangent).

The result should be something like:

```
radius  = 3.754
xcenter = 6.825
ycenter = 4.866
```

**The final C# function made out of the accepted answer**

```
    public static bool GetCircleFromLineLineCircle()
    {
        //The given values
        double P1_x = 7;
        double P1_y = 10;
        double P2_x = 11;
        double P2_y = 6;
        double P3_x = 12;
        double P3_y = 3;
        double P4_x = 5;
        double P4_y = 0;
        double C_x = 2;
        double C_y = 8;
        double C_radius = 2;

        //1. Horizontal and vertical distance between line points
        double d1_x = P2_x - P1_x;
        double d1_y = P2_y - P1_y;
        double d2_x = P4_x - P3_x;
        double d2_y = P4_y - P3_y;

        //2. Find the intersection of the two lines containing the two line segments.
        double denom = d1_y * d2_x - d1_x * d2_y;

        //Return false if lines are parallel or coincident
        if (denom == 0) { return false; }

        //Intersection point
        double T = ((P1_x - P3_x) * d2_y + (P3_y - P1_y) * d2_x) / denom;
        double I_x = P1_x + d1_x * T;
        double I_y = P1_y + d1_y * T;

        //3. Calculate the vector extending from intersection to center
        double V_x = C_x - I_x;
        double V_y = C_y - I_y;

        //4. Calculate the dot product of vector with d1 and d2:
        double dotp1 = V_x * d1_x + V_y * d1_y;
        double dotp2 = V_x * d2_x + V_y * d2_y;

        //If sign is negative, negative line points
        if (Math.Sign(dotp1) == -1) { d1_x = -d1_x; d1_y = -d1_y; }
        if (Math.Sign(dotp2) == -1) { d2_x = -d2_x; d2_y = -d2_y; }

        //5. Calculate the direction vector of the bisector
        double dist1 = Math.Sqrt(d1_x * d1_x + d1_y * d1_y);
        double dist2 = Math.Sqrt(d2_x * d2_x + d2_y * d2_y);
        double U_x = d1_x / dist1 + d2_x / dist2;
        double U_y = d1_y / dist1 + d2_y / dist2;

        //6. A point on the bisector
        double dotp_U_d1 = U_x * d1_x + U_y * d1_y;
        double dotp_U_U = U_x * U_x + U_y * U_y;
        double dotp_d1_d1 = d1_x * d1_x + d1_y * d1_y;
        double theta = Math.Acos(dotp_U_d1 / (Math.Sqrt(dotp_U_U) * Math.Sqrt(dotp_d1_d1)));

        //7. The equation we want to solve
        double dotp_V_U = V_x * U_x + V_y * U_y;
        double dotp_V_V = V_x * V_x + V_y * V_y;
        double cos2_theta = Math.Pow(Math.Cos(theta), 2);
        double a = dotp_U_U * cos2_theta;
        double b = -2 * dotp_V_U - 2 * C_radius * Math.Sqrt(dotp_U_U) * Math.Sin(theta);
        double c = dotp_V_V - C_radius * C_radius;
        double discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
        double t1 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
        double t2 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);

        //8. Calculate the center and C_radius
        //Solution 1
        double C1_x = I_x + t1 * U_x;
        double C1_y = I_y + t1 * U_y;
        double C1_radius = t1 * Math.Abs(Math.Sqrt(dotp_U_U)) * Math.Sin(theta);
        //Solution 2
        double C2_x = I_x + t2 * U_x;
        double C2_y = I_y + t2 * U_y;
        double C2_radius = t2 * Math.Abs(Math.Sqrt(dotp_U_U)) * Math.Sin(theta);

        Console.WriteLine($"C1_x: {C1_x:0.0##}  C1_y: {C1_y:0.0##}  C1_radius: {C1_radius:0.0##}");
        //C1_x: 6.825  C1_y: 4.866  C1_radius: 3.754

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The image isn't correct. The circle will be on the first line, since the center of that circle is on the line. So i'm not sure what circle are you trying to find.

Comment: @SuperDedo You are right, I fixed the typo in the question, the centerpoint of the known circle was not correct.

Comment: The variable 'ua' can be outside the interval $[0, 1]$, you should not return with false if this occurs, you should continue on to finding the intersection point.

Comment: @GloriousNathalie I have worked on the C# code some more, in step 5 I get different values (U_x: -0.212  U_y: -1.101)

Comment: In Step 4. in your code, Do not swap the end points if the condition is true, instead just negate d_1 or d_2 as follows :  d1_x = - d1_x  and  d1_y = -d1_y  or d2_x = -d2_x  and d2_y = -d2_y

Comment: @GloriousNathalie Thanks! So now I've written step 6, also wrong values comming out

Comment: Which value is the wrong value ?  I see you have computed $\theta$ correctly.

Comment: Ah yea the value 2.743 is squared in your example, nevermind :) I'm still on the right track...

Comment: @GloriousNathalie How can you get t1 and t2 from the equation in step 7?
I can't figure it out...

Comment: Use the quadratic formula.  It is as follows.  For the equation $a t^2 + b t + c = 0 $, calculate the the discriminant $d = b^2 - 4 a c $, then the two roots are $t_1 = (- b - \sqrt{d} ) / (2 a) $ and $t_2 = (-b + \sqrt{d} ) / (2 a) $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144428/discussion-between-sander-and-glorious-nathalie).

Comment: Excellent work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in the question, the center of the unknown circle will lie on the angle bisector of the lines that contain the given line segments.  But there are two such bisectors.

To know which bisector to use, we have to locate the center of the given circle within the four segments of the plane defined by the two lines.  This is easy to do, as all it takes is finding the dot product of the vector from the intersection of the two lines to the center with the direction vectors of the two lines.

So using the given values, we have

$P_1 = (7,10) , P_2 = (11, 6) , P_3 = (12, 3) , P_4= (5,0) $

Given circle :  $C = (2, 8) $ , $ r = 2 $

1. Define

$ d_1 = P_2 - P_1 = (4, -4) $

$ d_2 = P_4 - P_3 = (-7, -3) $

2. Find the intersection of the two lines containing the two line segments.

$ I = P_1 + t d_1 = P_3 + s d_2 $

$ (7, 10) + t ( 4, -4) = (12, 3) + s (-7, -3) $

Therefore,

$4 t + 7 s = 5$

$-4 t + 3 s = -7 $

Adding gives  $ 10 s = -2 $,  so $ s = - \dfrac{1}{5} $

Hence, the intersection points is

$I = P_3 + s d_2 = (12, 3) - \dfrac{1}{5} (-7, -3) = \dfrac{1}{5}(67 , 18 ) $

3. Calculate the vector extending from I to C

$ V = IC = C - I = (2, 8) - \dfrac{1}{5} (67, 18) = \dfrac{1}{5} (-57, 22) $

4. Calculate the sign of the dot product of $V$ with $d_1$ and $d_2$:

$ V \cdot d_1 = \dfrac{1}{5} (-57, 22) \cdot (4, -4) \lt 0 $

$ V \cdot d_2 = \dfrac{1}{5}(-57, 22) \cdot (-7, -3) \gt 0 $

4. If the dot product of $V$ with $d_i$ is negative, reverse the direction of $d_i$ and re-assign to $d_i$

Using this, our new direction vectors will be

$ d_1 = (-4, 4) , d_2 = (-7, -3) $

5. Calculate the direction vector of the bisector as follows

$ U =  \dfrac{d_1}{\| d_1 \| } + \dfrac{d_2} { \| d_2 \| } $

This gives

$ U = \dfrac{ (-4, 4) }{ 4 \sqrt{2} } + \dfrac{ (-7, -3) } { \sqrt{ 58 } } $

Numerically, this evaluates to

$ U = (-1.6262518, 0.3131875 ) $

6. A point on the bisector has the parametric form

$ P = I + t U $ where $ t \gt 0 $

We want the distance $(\overline{PC} - r )$ to be equal to the perpendicular distance between $P$ and the two lines, i.e. we want

$ (\| PC \| - r) = \| I + t U -  C \| = \| PI \| \sin \theta $

where $\theta $ is the angle between the direction of the bisector $U$ and either $d_1$ or $d_2$, so

$ \theta = \cos^{-1} \left(\dfrac{ U \cdot d_1 }{\sqrt{U \cdot U} \sqrt{d_1 \cdot d_1}} \right)$

Numerically, this evaluates to

$ \theta = \cos^{-1} \left(\dfrac{7.7577572} { (1.65613445)(4 \sqrt{2}) }\right) = \cos^{-1}( 0.828067237) = 0.595145 \text{ radians} $

7. So the equation we want to solve is

$ \| PC \| - r = \| I + t U - C \| - r = \| PI \| \sin \theta $

Re-arranging,

$ \| I - C + t U \|  = t \| U \| \sin \theta  + r $

Squaring, we obtain

$ (I - C) \cdot (I - C) + 2 t (I - C) \cdot U + t^2 ( U \cdot U )  =  t^2 \| U \|^2 \sin^2 \theta + 2 r t \| U \| \sin \theta  + r^2 $

Recall that $ V = C - I $

Therefore the above equation reduces to

$ V \cdot V + t (-2 V \cdot U - 2 r \|U \| \sin \theta ) + t^2 (U \cdot U) \cos^2 \theta - r^2 = 0 $

Numerically, the above equation evaluates to

$  145.32 - 43.5485 t + 1.8807123 t^2 = 0 $

The roots of this quadratic equation in $t$ are

$ t_1 = 4.04283 $

$ t_2 = 19.1125 $

Since both $t$'s are positive, they're both valid solutions.

Using the first value of $t$, we can obtain the center of the radius of the unknown circle

The center is:
$ P = I + t U =  \dfrac{1}{5}(67 , 18 ) + 4.04283 (-1.6262518, 0.3131875 ) = (6.82534, 4.8661) $

And the radius given by $ t \|U\| \sin \theta = 4.04283 (1.65613445 ) \sin 0.595145 = 3.75367 $

Comment: This looks like a very solid answer, well explained! Next week I will try it.

Comment: Now that I think of it, there might be several answers possible and you have to be careful about it: think about what if the given circle center is one either of the straight lines. Though maybe it's not really a problem in the context of the real problem of @Sander.

Comment: @GloriousNathalie: I try to translate the formulas into C# code, but have trouble understanding some things. in Step 2: which parameters lead to the I (intersection) outcome?

Comment: @Qise Yes, that's a good point. At the end, I have to test different situations. First, I will try to get a working function and afterwards, finetune with if statements.

Comment: @Sander, I have updated my answer to explicitly show how point $I$ is calculated. (i.e. which variables/vectors are used in the calculation)

Comment: I still have many questions that I don't understand. Where does the **s** and **t** come from in step 3? and  in step 5 there are numbers that are squared, are those the d1 and d2?

Comment: The parametric equation of the first line specified by $P_1 $ and $P_2$ is $ P_1 + t d_1$ and similarly the parametric equation of the second line specified by $P_3$ and $P_4$ is $P_3 + s d_2 $, the intersection point $I$ is where these two expressions are equal, and this happens at a unique $t$ and $s$.  In step $5$, we calculate the direction vector of the bisector, this is equal to the sum of the unit vectors along $d_1$ and $d_2$ as given by the equation in step $5$.  The square roots come from the lengths of $d_1$ and $d_2$.

Comment: I have made some progress in writing the steps into C# code (as updated in my post), but I am struggling to filter out the necessary formulas and translate them into the code. I greatly appreciate your help thus far, but I must admit that my knowledge of math is limited, especially when it comes to more complex problems.

Comment: I don't think the formulas can be simplified further.  If you have more questions, I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You almost solved the problem on yourself when you said the center of the circle you seek is on the bisector of the two lines.

With these names: [image: these]

You have to solve $d(C_c, C) - rad_C= d(C,x_1)$ which will yield a second degree equation. You can pick the right answer by using the fact $C$ is on the bisector.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. However, my math skills are not good enough to solve this comparison. Apparently, I only have to know the radius of the unknown circle since I know where the center should be.

Comment: if you know the position of the center then you can just compute directly the distance to either of the lines

Comment: Yes, that would be easy, problem is that everything about this circle is unknown except the distance from all other 3 objects is the same and it should lay somewhere on the bisector from the two lines

Comment: You can directly find the big circle center and radius numerically from Qise's given Geogebra construction of circle touching two lines and the given smaller circle.

Comment: @Narasimham Can Geogebra give the formula's to calculate the unknown?

Comment: No.  From  answer by given by @GloriousErin give symbols and carry simplifications  through to the last step retaining the symbols.